# pypyodbc connection to Filemaker throws "list index out of range" error

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, filemaker, pypyodbc

Trying to connect a python script to our filemaker db. It was working with a previous copy of db but recently connecting to new version, it started throwing an error  "list index out of range" when trying to grab a table from the DB.

Using Python 3.7.4, pypyodbc 1.3.4, and filemaker Pro 13.0v3
Also using Filemaker ODBC driver 13.2.14

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM Projects'
con_str = "DSN=%s;Database=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s" % (DSN, DB, User, PW)
with pypyodbc.connect(con_str) as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()              
    cursor.execute(query)
```

The connection is correctly established or at least, returns the correct object. And I assure there is a table that corresponds to the query:
[image: List of tables]

Some previous noise regarding a similar error that supposedly has been resolved in subsequent releases:
[pypyodbc execute returns list index out of range error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396655/pypyodbc-execute-returns-list-index-out-of-range-error)

also tried setting Autocommit to True, but still get error:

Any help is appreciated.

Edit - added traceback per request:

```
    <ipython-input-8-de64dadd5741> in <module>
      4 with pypyodbc.connect(con_str, autocommit = True) as connection:
      5     cursor = connection.cursor()
----> 6     cursor.execute(query)
      7     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
      8 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\submittal_client_env\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py in execute(self, query_string, params, many_mode, call_mode)
   1624 
   1625         else:
-> 1626             self.execdirect(query_string)
   1627         return self
   1628 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\submittal_client_env\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py in execdirect(self, query_string)
   1652         check_success(self, ret)
   1653         self._NumOfRows()
-> 1654         self._UpdateDesc()
   1655         #self._BindCols()
   1656         return self

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\submittal_client_env\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py in _UpdateDesc(self)
   1774                 10, ADDR(c_short()),ADDR(Cdisp_size))
   1775             if ret != SQL_SUCCESS:
-> 1776                 check_success(self, ret)
   1777 
   1778             if force_unicode:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\submittal_client_env\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py in check_success(ODBC_obj, ret)
   1005     if ret not in (SQL_SUCCESS, SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO, SQL_NO_DATA):
   1006         if isinstance(ODBC_obj, Cursor):
-> 1007             ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
   1008         elif isinstance(ODBC_obj, Connection):
   1009             ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\submittal_client_env\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py in ctrl_err(ht, h, val_ret, ansi)
    970             #No more data, I can raise
    971             #print(err_list[0][1])
--> 972             state = err_list[0][0]
    973             err_text = raw_s('[')+state+raw_s('] ')+err_list[0][1]
    974             if state[:2] in (raw_s('24'),raw_s('25'),raw_s('42')):

IndexError: list index out of range`enter code here`
    enter code here
```

Comment: ... You haven't shown the traceback

Comment: added traceback, roganjosh.